# zenmap/nmap vs SoftPerfect Network Scanner

Tags: scanner, nmap

Do you use both or either or neither? Which one do you like or prefer?

I like the double reverse lookup feature on SoftPerfect Network Scanner. Is similar feature also available on nmap? If so, what will be the parameters?

Thanks,
/S

Answer (score 0):

I have not used SoftPerfect Network Scanner, but I was interested enough in your question to implement "double-reverse lookup" for Nmap. The NSE script is called [fcrdns](http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/fcrdns.html) and implements *forward-confirmed reverse DNS* lookups. Some features that may make this Nmap script more useful than SoftPerfect's version include:

- IPv6 (AAAA record) lookups.
- Reporting of missing records (no PTR record or no A/AAAA record).
- Proper handling of multiple PTR records, an uncommon real-world case.
- Reporting of all addresses that reverse names forward-resolve to.

Comment: did u use the script in windows?

Comment: Nmap is fully cross-platform. The script ought to work with the [latest release of Nmap.](http://nmap.org/download.html)